# Как сформировать список из выдачи python

Tags: python, list, dict

```
user_json = json.loads(r.text)

for i in user_json['result']:
    try:
        list =[]
        arr2 = i['owner_products'][0]['id'], i['ip'].split(';')
        list.append(arr2)
        print(arr2)
    except:
        pass
```

Исходный вид:

```
{'result': [{'serial_number': '2112ALSN0J8000014', 'location_key': None, 'type': 'TYPE_HARDWARE_SERVER', 'os': 'Linux', 'owner_products': [{'name': 'ЭЧ', 'id': 11}], 'own': True, 'i_id': 1406824, 'dat_name': '', 'id': 553, 'ip': '10.0.0.56;172.15.217.56', 'hostname': 'test', 'model': 'Huawei'}
```

Вывод:

```
(11, ['10.0.0.56', '172.15.217.56'])
```

А мне надо:

```
[(11, '172.15.217.56')]
[(11, '10.0.0.56')]
```

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример исходного словаря / JSON'а

Comment: Не называйте свою переменную `list`, а то сюрпризы потом будут

Comment: `arr2 = [ (i['owner_products'][0]['id'], x) for x in i['ip'].split(';') ]`

Comment: @GrAnd не работает таким макаром

Comment: @MaxU добавил в вопрос исходный вывод

Comment: @user3119496 Всё работает. Сами проверьте: `i = {'owner_products':[{'id':111}], 'ip':'11.217.216.67;11.217.224.67;11.217.224.100'}
arr2 = [ (i['owner_products'][0]['id'], x) for x in i['ip'].split(';') ]
print(arr2)`

Comment: @GrAnd [(111, '11.217.216.67'), (111, '11.217.224.67'), (111, '11.217.224.100')] вот так получается,а надо [(111, '11.217.216.67')] новая строка [(111, '11.217.224.67')] новая строку  [(111, '11.217.224.100')]

Comment: @user3119496 В вашем вопросе совсем другой запрос. А потом, что мешает печатать как вам хочется? Ведь главное как хранится, а не как на экран выводится. А как надо хранить, вы, похоже, и сами не определились ещё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странное вы что-то хотите, зачем вам кортежи внутри списков, например? Ну да ладно, пусть будет:

```
for i in user_json['result']:
    try:
        lst =[]
        id_ = i['owner_products'][0]['id']
        for ip in i['ip'].split(';'):
            arr2 = [(id_, ip)]
            lst.append(arr2)
            print(arr2)
    except:
        pass
```

Вывод:

```
[(11, '10.0.0.56')]
[(11, '172.15.217.56')]
```

Содержимое `lst` в итоге:

```
[[(11, '10.0.0.56')], [(11, '172.15.217.56')]]
```